# Microsoft Graph client error : Authentication challenge is required

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to access office 365 users using Graph SDK provided by Microsoft in NuGet my code is :

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("ClientId")
                .WithClientSecret("ClientSecret")
                .WithTenantId("TenantId")
                .Build();

List<string> scopess = new List<string>();
scopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
scopes.Add("Calendars.Read");
// i tried each scope alone and same result
var authenticationProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(cca, scopes.ToArray());
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var x = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

on the last line i am getting the error

> Authentication challenge is required

my Azure Active Directory app registration settings are :
[image]
[image]
[image]

probably i am doing something wrong but not sure what!
I am using the Microsoft Docs as a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [client credential provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider).

Replace `var authenticationProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(cca, scopes.ToArray());` with `ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(cca);`

And note that you define `GraphServiceClient graphClient` but you are using `graphClient2` in the next line: `graphClient2.Users.Request().GetAsync()`. Please Check it.

Comment: Yeah since in the app registration _Application_ permissions are defined, you need to use client credentials flow to get the token, not authorization code flow.

Comment: @maces If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: i need to wait 10 minutes before accepting, will do that

Comment: How do you identify which flow is being used? I'm intending to use the Authorization Code flow but running into this same error that OP asked about...

Comment: @Ortund Refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider to check if you are using the correct code.

Comment: @AllenWu so the provider that I'm using determines which flow I'm using? I've actually been referencing that code although it is a bit incomplete on account of `scopes` not being declared